# Dynamically Chain Django Forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

In a Django 1.11 app I've created a large form for users to update a model instance, but based on what the users change there may be multiple other forms I'd like to redirect them to afterwards.

What's the best practise for dynamically chaining multiple forms (dynamic workflow)?

I can't find anything helpful in the Django docs or other questions on here.

E.g. (extremely simplified) view for model update form:

```
def asset_edit(request, pk):
    asset = get_object_or_404(Asset, pk=pk)
    current_location_concat = "{} {} {}".format(asset.location_building, asset.location_room, asset.location_area)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EditAsset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=asset)
            if form.is_valid():
                asset = form.save(commit=False)
                # setting some things...
                asset.save()
                new_location_concat = "{} {} {}".format(asset.location_building, asset.location_room, asset.location_area)

                if current_location_concat != new_location_concat:
                    check_relatives = True    # redirect to check_relatives form

                if asset.equipment_id:
                    if Asset.objects.filter(equipment_id=asset.equipment_id).count() > 1:
                        duplicate_assets = True    # redirect to check_duplicates form

                # if check_relatives and duplicate_assets:
                    # redirect to check_duplicates form and then on to check_relatives form

                return redirect("asset_detail", pk=asset.pk)
```

I know I could just add a new URL for my check_duplicates form with a "next" (or similar) parameter, pass a "next" value that the check_duplicate view maps to one or more other forms (just "check_relatives" in this instance) and redirects to this when the check_duplicates form is submitted, but is this the best practise?

Especially given that the number of forms that may need to be chained this way could get quite large and the logic complex!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using [formtool's WizardView](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for this and I have tried the 'stuff-everything-into-the-post-method' approach as well.

WizardView looks like the right fit for what you are trying to do. 
For example, it allows you to skip steps in your workflow based on function conditions - removing this bit of logic from your workflow, which makes the whole view easier to read.

I have found it a pain to write tests for such views as you have to account for the WizardView's very own internal structure while testing, but overall it's definitely better than writing a 1000 lines post-method (might as well code in BASIC then).

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm looking into django-formtools now!  Just wish their documentation was a bit clearer.  Looks like it was part of Django until 1.8 when they split it out into it's own package?